# Merge two .mka files generated by twilio

Tags: android, twilio

I'm developing an app which uses twilio programmable video.
Twilio records each participant in its different file. I mean if there is two participant in the room, twilio will generate two .mka files, each for participant.
Also twilio calls a service in my side when every event happens.
Finally I have the recordings each one in a url for that .mka file. I have to merge them in a one recording.

Is there any library that takes two urls and make a single file of recording?

**Important Note** : each recording has its start time, so playing both files asynchronously will cause voice mismatch.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input1.mka -i input2.mka -filter_complex emerge audio.mka`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Alex suggests, ffmpeg is a good program for merging audio files.

You might also be interested in the [Twilio Recording Composition API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource) which is an API that lets you use Twilio's resources to merge recordings that have been created by the Video API.

Comment: Even if this is too late to answer, but it's the correct answer. Thanks a lot.